# Unity 2D Help (Bounce)

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

As in the illustration, each time the ball evenly based on an ongoing basis to a height equal to progress.

Comment: can not you see the visual

Comment: Please **visit** the **[help center](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and take the tour to see what and how to ask.

Answer (score 1):

**Set a physics material 2D to your ball with Bounciness of 1.**

How to do it:

-Right click on empty space in your *Project assets -> Create --> PhysicsMaterial2D*
-Set *name to the material*, something like "Bouncy"
-On the *inspector change "Bounciness" to 1.*